# Listview shows wrong images

Tags: android, listview, lazy-loading, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with an ArrayAdapter holding rows with a Image and a String. This worked fine until I decided that the loading of the images was to slow so I could not load the images before showing the list. So I started to load the images in a separate thread using an `AsyncTask`.

I was very happy with the result until I started to scroll the list.  Wrong images was loaded and it doesn't look like it is a question of the image getting a while later. If I attempt to sort the list the problem goes really bad and none of the images is on the right row.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.drink_list_row, null);
        }

        Drink drink = allItems.get(position);
        if (drink != null && v != null) {
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkName);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadImageBitmap(drink, imageView);
            textView.setText(drink.getName());

            if (subItems != null && subItems.contains(drink)) {
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from your convertView: it's the same single instance that is used throughout the list, so when your asynchronous loading is complete, the image is changed when the listview is trying to paint a different item using the same convertView (or in that case, its child imageView).

```
painting position 1, uses placeholder, starts loading image 1 asynchronously
painting position 2, uses placeholder, starts loading image 2 asynchronously
image 1 loading is complete, calling setImageBitmap on imageView
painting position 3, uses image 1, starts loading image 3 asynchronously
etc.
```

What you can do though is keep a cache of Bitmaps in the listadapter. Something like this:

```
private Bitmap[] bitmapList;
private Bitmap bitmapPlaceholder;  

private void initBitmapListWithPlaceholders(){ 
// call this whenever the list size changes
// you can also use a list or a map or whatever so you 
// don't need to drop all the previously loaded bitmap whenever 
// the list contents are modified
    int count = getListCount();
    bitmapList = new Bitmap[count];
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
         bitmapList[i]=bitmapPlaceholder
    }
}

private void onBitmapLoaded(int position, Bitmap bmp){
// this is your callback when the load async is done
    bitmapList[position] = bmp;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.drink_list_row, null);
    }

    Drink drink = allItems.get(position);
    if (drink != null && v != null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.drinkName);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmapList[position]);
        loadImageBitmap(drink, position); // this should call onBitmapLoaded(int position, Bitmap bmp) when finished to update the bitmapList and replace the placeholder
        textView.setText(drink.getName());

        if (subItems != null && subItems.contains(drink)) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: I ran into this problem and solved it in a similar way. However, I'm now seeing images not appear in a listview item until the item has been scrolled out and back into view. Any ideas on how to force item updates?

Comment: @cacois start new question, but invalidate on the listview would work.