# How to cache imageview in listview?

Tags: android, listview, caching, bitmap, imageview

I am having the same problem as this guy
[Listview shows wrong images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081497/listview-shows-wrong-images)

I saw the solution that I have to cache it. But in my cache, I am not sure how to apply the cache given in the solution. I keep receiving error.

I suspect this is the part i have problem with:

```
holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmapList[position]);

            //loadImageBitmap(mObjects.get(position), position);

            //onBitmapLoaded(position, holder.mTask.myBitmap());
```

Below are the codes.
Adapter.java
    public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    private static final String TAG = "Adapter";
    private Activity mActivity;
    public ArrayList<Data> mObjects;

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView title;
        WebView newimage;
        DownloadImageTask mTask;
        public void setOnClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }



    private Bitmap[] bitmapList;
    private Bitmap bitmapPlaceholder;  

    private void initBitmapListWithPlaceholders(){ 
    // call this whenever the list size changes
    // you can also use a list or a map or whatever so you 
    // don't need to drop all the previously loaded bitmap whenever 
    // the list contents are modified
        int count = getCount();
        bitmapList = new Bitmap[count];
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
             bitmapList[i]=bitmapPlaceholder;
        }
    }

    private void onBitmapLoaded(int position, Bitmap bmp){
    // this is your callback when the load async is done
        bitmapList[position] = bmp;
    }

    public Adapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {

        this.mActivity = (Activity) activity;
        this.mObjects = mObjects;


    }

    public void setObjects(ArrayList<Data> mObjects) {
        this.mObjects = mObjects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Data item = mObjects.get(position);
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);


            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.icon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            viewHolder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            viewHolder.newimage =(WebView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.newimage);


            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        holder.title.setText(item.getmTitle());

        //String html = " <html><head></head><body><p font-size='8px'>" +  item.getmImageUrl() + "</p><img src='" + item.getmImageUrl() + "' width='100%' height='100%'></body></html>";
        String html = " <html><head></head><body><img src='" + item.getmImageUrl() + "' width='100%' height='100%'></body></html>";




        holder.newimage.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");

        holder.newimage.setFocusable(false);
        holder.newimage.setClickable(false);
        holder.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            private Object title;

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(Adapter.this,"Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("log_tag",this.title.toString() + " clicked");
            }
        });

        //holder.icon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        holder.mTask = new DownloadImageTask(item.getmImageUrl(), holder.icon);


        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmapList[position]);

        //loadImageBitmap(mObjects.get(position), position);

        //onBitmapLoaded(position, holder.mTask.myBitmap());
        if (!holder.mTask.isCancelled()) {
            holder.mTask.execute();
        }


        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return (this.mObjects.size());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return (this.mObjects.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return (position);
    }

    public AbsListView.RecyclerListener mRecyclerListener = new RecyclerListener( ){

        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            DownloadImageTask imagetask = viewHolder.mTask;
            if (imagetask != null) {
                imagetask.cancel(true);
            }
        }

    };

    public void setOnClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

DownloadImageTask.java

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    public Bitmap g;
    private String mUrl;
    private ImageView mImageView = null;

    public DownloadImageTask(String Url, ImageView imageView) {

        mUrl = Url;
        this.mImageView = imageView;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            //result.recycle();
        }
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(mUrl);
        return bitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl) {
        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        try {

            /*URL newurl = new URL(imageUrl); 
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); */
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

            /*
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));*/


            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream (in));
            //mBitmap.recycle();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.g = mBitmap;
        return mBitmap;
    }

    public Bitmap myBitmap() {
        Bitmap fg;
        fg = (Bitmap) g;

        return fg;
    }

    static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
            super(inputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
            while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                    int b = read();
                    if (b < 0) {
                        break;  // we reached EOF
                    } else {
                        bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                    }
                }
                totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
            }
            return totalBytesSkipped;
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT

I have modified DownloadImageTask.java to do some caching by following this code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7730547

But I seem to have problem on this lines:

```
if (!(this.mImageView.getTag().toString()).equals(this.mUrl)) {
            /* The path is not same. This means that this
               image view is handled by some other async task. 
               We don't do anything and return. */
            return;
         }
```

Because of the if... line, the app always crashes. This is getting super frustrating. I need help. Please help me. Below is the modified DownloadImageTask.Java

```
import java.io.FilterInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    public Bitmap g;
    private String mUrl;
    private ImageView mImageView = null;

    public DownloadImageTask(String Url, ImageView imageView) {


        mUrl = Url;
        this.mImageView = imageView;




    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        /*
        if (result != null) {
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
        */
        if (!(this.mImageView.getTag().toString()).equals(this.mUrl)) {
            /* The path is not same. This means that this
               image view is handled by some other async task. 
               We don't do anything and return. */
            return;
         }

         if(result != null && mImageView != null){
             mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
             mImageView.setTag(this.mUrl);
         }else{
             mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }


    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = getBitmap(mUrl);
        return bitmap;




    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap(String imageUrl) {


        Bitmap mBitmap = null;
        try {

            /*URL newurl = new URL(imageUrl); 
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); */
            //mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

            /*
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(is));*/


            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageUrl).openStream();
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream (in));


            //this.mImageView.setTag(this.mUrl);
            //mBitmap.recycle();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.g = mBitmap;

            return mBitmap;

    }

    public Bitmap myBitmap() {
        Bitmap fg;
        fg = (Bitmap) g;

        return fg;
    }

    static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
            super(inputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
            while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                    int b = read();
                    if (b < 0) {
                        break;  // we reached EOF
                    } else {
                        bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                    }
                }
                totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
            }
            return totalBytesSkipped;
        }
    }






}
```

Comment: Hi all...although I receive 1 response, i need something that is along the line that I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing this manually using `AsyncTask` and such you could use a caching library.
Android Query is a pretty good one: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/

To load images with Android Query you can use the following code inside the `getView` method of your ListView adapter:

```
AQuery _aq = new AQuery(mActivity);
_aq.id(R.id.icon).image("IMAGE_URI_TO_LOAD");
```

This should replace the `holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bitmapList[position]);` call.

This will load, cache and show the image from the Uri in the imageview. If the image is already cached, it will auto-load from the cache instead.

For more information on how to use this library for image loading you can check here: http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/ImageLoading

Comment: Still does not solve my problem. There is an error at the mContext. I replaced with 'this','Adapter.this', 'Adapter.java' and still have problems...

Comment: I've edited the answer. Try using mActivity instead of mContext

Comment: Not working either. I have no idea...@__@ By the way, i updated my post on the DownloadImageTask.java. I can't get it to work.

Comment: Not able to call the AQuery. new AQuery(mActivty).

Comment: Have you imported the AQuery library into your project? (by adding the AQuery jar files to the libs folder of your project)

Comment: Yup. Then build path. Yup. There is no error importing AQuery. Just error calling the class. There is a red zigzag line under the 'mActivity'